# What kind of algorithm is used in Nearby Search requests of Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am collecting data by using Nearby Search requests in Google Places API. 
I know these requests return maximum 60 results.

However, I want to know how these results are chosen. What kind of algorithm is working behind this "Nearby Search request"?

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=ja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google answers this in the [linked documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) when describing the `rankBy` parameter:

> `prominence` (**default**). This option sorts results based on their
>   importance. Ranking will favor prominent places within the specified
>   area. Prominence can be affected by a place's ranking in Google's
>   index, global popularity, and other factors.

You may also rank results by `distance` if you specify it explicitly. Otherwise, as per the above, the order defaults to `prominence`.

Hope this helps!